# Detect whether a Youtube video is licensed or not

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I got the new API cURL working for me for requesting video informations, I want to get the "licensed" info, tried with a music video, it worked, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QxFh.png).

My problem here is that I even tried it with a normal video, I got the same `"licensedContent": true` How can I detect if the music video is actually licensed?
For an example here is shakira's song and the description of the license [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIwrL.png).

Comment: Can you share us the video id such a "normal video" ?

Comment: yea sure the music video is: DUT5rEU6pqM , and the normal video is: th5_9woFJmk , for an example i want to get a response from  youtube's api about wither which one is licensed to youtube by someone or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer:

The following answer isn't complying with the [YouTube operational API](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) specification, you should instead follow [my other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266) on enumerating the musics in the given video. That way by checking whether or not the video contains musics you can deduce if the video is licensed or not.

### Deprecated answer:

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/d38a63c38993e44d0868bd7215e11a2d690a90e4/videos.php#L131) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=containsMusic&id=VIDEO_ID you'll get the boolean whether or not the video contains a music in `item["containsMusic"]`.

Examples:

- [Hips don't lie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUT5rEU6pqM):
  https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=containsMusic&id=DUT5rEU6pqM
  (returning `"containsMusic": true`)
- [A not music
  video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZRgVX8SYX4):
  https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=containsMusic&id=6ZRgVX8SYX4
  (returning `"containsMusic": false`)

Comment: Thank you soo much for your suggestion <3

Comment: [@ftk789](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16920828/ftk789) Note that [I significantly updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71497746/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

`licensedContent`

means that the content was uploaded to a channel linked to a YouTube content partner and then claimed by that partner.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent

Comment: Now that makes much more sense, but is there a way to actually detect licensed youtube videos? like a music video or so...